# How to filter in HTML using a field from model?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a page with check boxes from university's subjects and the user can select which ones are already completed, I code a for loop that displays in the page all subjects from that course, but I want to separate the subjects by semester in a div, but in the same page, can I do this with a custom template tag or filter?

I have tried using .filter on the query, but in this case only returned one specified semester.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `regroup` template tag can help.

Example template code:

```
{% regroup subjects by semester as semester_list %}

{% for semester, grouped_subjects in semester_list %}
<div>
    {# your code for semester here #}
    <div>
    {% for subject in grouped_subjects %}
        {# your code for subject here #}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Read more on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

——

Edit:

`regroup` relies on ordering of the queryset.

Change the first line in above code to

```
{% regroup subjects|dictsort:'semester' by semester as semester_list %}
```

Comment: I think that could work, but I am having problems defining the semester variable, it is not in the model class subject, how could I do it?

Comment: Does `Subject` model class have any attributes related to (or can be converted to) semester? If so, do the conversion and you can do the `regroup` then.

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVFZo.png) I did it, but doesn't seem like it's organizing, see? The subject names are in Portuguese, the semester is the number, like 3 is third semester

Comment: This is likely caused by ordering of your queryset, and can be solved by either doing the sort in your view function, or using `dictsort` template filter. I will edit my answer to include this part.